# Change image of radio button when clicked with css

Tags: php, css, radio-button

I created a radio button css following tips on the stackoverflow, but there is a little detail missing.

It prints out a red square instead of default radio button icon, but when I click it, nothing happens.

There is the code:
In the for loop I have:

```
$radioprint[$j] .= '<div class="radio"><div><input type="radio" name="radio'.$j.'" value="'.$radioarr[$j][$r].'">
<label for="radio'.$j.'"></label>'.$radioarr[$j][$r].'</div></div>';
```

And I adjusted the css:

```
input[type=radio]{display:none;}
label {
width: 14px;height: 14px;display: inline-block;background-color: red;cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
width: 14px;height: 14px;display: inline-block;background-color: green;cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have tried some workaround with CSS only to make it work (used 3 radios for testing, you can make it from the loop).

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<input class="rb" value="1" id="a1" type="radio" name="myradio" checked="checked">
<label for="a1" class="radio_label"><div class="new_button"></div><span class="whitespan"> Radio 1</span></label><br />

<input class="rb" value="2" id="a2" type="radio" name="myradio">
<label for="a2" class="radio_label"><div class="new_button"></div><span class="whitespan"> Radio 2</span></label><br />

<input class="rb" value="3" id="a3" type="radio" name="myradio">
<label for="a3" class="radio_label"><div class="new_button"></div><span class="whitespan"> Radio 3</span></label>
```

**CSS:**

```
.rb { display:none }
.new_button {width:15px; display:inline-block}
.whitespan { background-color: white }
.radio_label { background-color:red; cursor: pointer }
input[type=radio]:checked+label { background-color: green }
```

Ok, let me explain how this works. There are 3 hidden radio-buttons hidden with **`display:none`** style. Label for each of radio-buttons contains **`div`** element (to simulate custom-draw of circles) and course text. I have placed text inside **`span`** pair and changed its background to white (or any background color you want).

After click on `label` you change background color of entire label, but white background of your text make it visually unaffected. That means that you can change colored-area of label just simply changing dimensions of inline `div` in front of text. Because `div` was placed inside `label` pair, you can get same click effect by clicking on colored squares too.

Actually, with label's `width` style-property you can define width of colored block. To change height you probably have to deal with `margins`, `padding`, `font-size`, or even by making more complex `nested` structure of div elements.

Honestly, this was my first attempt to make something like this. Never used anything similar in my life. So it's certainly not perfect solution, but at least consider it and try to make something usable to fit your needs.

Hope you can use it.